# How can we plot four dimensional planes and how the planes intersect?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am well concerned about the three dimensional planes but don't know how to plot four dimensional planes. So help me plotting $3$ four dimensional planes $u+v+w+z=6,u+w+z=4,u+w=2$. Regards

Comment: Can you see in four dimensions? :o

Comment: @Ritz not at all. But how can we observe their intersection, whether the intersection is a line or a plane or a point for these ?

Comment: I advise you to do a 3D representation in the $u,w,z$ space, taking $v$ as a parameter, and try different values of $v$ (value $v=2$ should be interesting, why ?)

Comment: Just for clarification, are you asking "how can we determine (with some algebra) whether their intersection is a line or plane or whatever?" or "how can we use pictures to visualize the intersection?"? Those two questions have very different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one coordinate as time, let's say $t = v$.

The planes $u+w+z = 4$, $u+w=2$ are fixed in $\mathbb{R}^3$, independent of time.

While as time progress, the plane $u + w + z = 6 - t$ moves till it intersects (at time instant $t = 2$).

Comment: we already have $u+v+z=4$ and can we take $t$ other than $2$ ?

Comment: The system you wrote consisted of $u+v+w+z=6$ and $u+w+z = 4$, so the second intersects the first at $v = 2$!

Comment: Then what is intersection of these three planes, whether a line or a point ?

Comment: A line. $v,z$ are fixed at $2$, and $u+w = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the last variable be represented by time.

[image]

Comment: You probably need to be able to see both $v=2$ and $z=2$ at the same time if you want to visualise intersections

Answer (score 1):

**Trick**:

All three equations contain the term $u+v$. Let us call it $t$.

Then

$$\begin{align}&t+z+v&=6\\
&t+z&=4\\
&t&=2\end{align}$$

is an ordinary 3D problem, giving the single point $t=2,z=2,v=2$, which is actually the line $u+v=2,z=2,v=2$.

(In fact, we were projecting 4D onto 3D, i.e. looking "in the direction of $u+v$".)

Answer (score 1):

Illustrations of three-dimensional planes and their intersections
are actually only two-dimensional drawings.
The image you see (collected by the retina of your eye)
also is two-dimensional.
You accept the idea that the third dimension was projected onto the image
and infer the structure it must have provided before
the projection.

You can also project four dimensions onto two, like this:

[image]

This figure depicts the hyperplane $u+w+z=4$ and the triangle
$(4,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,4,0)$, $(0,0,0,4)$ where it intersects the
$uvw$-, $vwz$-, and $uvz$-hyperplanes.
It depicts the hyperplane $u+w+z=6$ and the tetrahedron
$(6,0,0,0)$, $(0,6,0,0)$, $(0,0,6,0)$, $(0,0,0,6)$
where it intersects the 
$uvw$-, $vwz$-, $uwz$-, and $uvz$-hyperplanes.
It also depicts the triangle $(4,2,0,0)$, $(0,2,4,0)$, $(0,2,0,4)$
in the plane of intersection of those two hyperplanes.

The shaded regions of course are only parts of each hyperplane;
in drawings of three-dimensional planes, if we colored in the
entire plane it would fill the picture with a
background color without adding any information, and the
same is true for these hyperplanes.

If we add the third hyperplane to the picture, the common
intersection of all three is the line containing the points
$(2,2,0,2)$ and $(0,2,2,2)$.
But it's better to start a new drawing for that intersection;
this one already has more going on than one can easily keep track of
(except possibly for some individuals who are
exceptionally good at four-dimensional visualization).